# How to convert laravel query column into array and match with variable array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to find `ids` into `$company->id`. `ids` and `$company->id` are both have comma separated string

```
 MOdel::where(explode(',', 'ids'), $company->id)
```

How do i arrange number in the `ids` and `$company->ids` and match if both has same values?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if 2 arrays have the same values then you have to sort the arrays and compare them like this:

```
$array1 = explode(',' $ids);
$array2 = explode(',' $companyIds);

sort($array1);
sort($array2);

if ($array1 == $array2) {
    dd('arrays are the same');
}
```

[image]

Comment: having `$company->id` also as a comma separated list as they describe kinda messes stuff up

Comment: actualy i want like to consider 'company_id' in where clause as array, actualy purpose is to compare two strings if string one is. str1 = 1,2,3,4 and str2=1,3,2,4, it should match and shoud be true. so suppose 1,2,3,4 is company_id in where clause and 1,3,2,4 is $company_id

Comment: `Model::where('company_id, $company->id)->exists()` shouldn't this be enough or I am not getting the question.

Comment: its not working. want to compare two strings if string one is. str1 = 1,2,3,4 and str2=1,3,2,4, it should match and shoud be true. so suppose 1,2,3,4 is company_id in where clause and 1,3,2,4 is $company_id, althoug in one string numbers are arranged and not arranged in the second string. but should match and return should true.

Comment: It is actually not clear what are you trying to do... I have shown you how to check if 2 strings, when converted to arrays are the same. But you are mentioning a where clause... are the ids and customer_ids 2 strings?

Comment: Lewis4u, actualy i want to compare two values, one is coming from database in where clause that is like 1,2,3,4 and second is variable value which is 1,2,4,3. i want result in true although both strings has un arranged values but both string has same values so result should be true.